# error TS2339: Property 'addForm' does not exist on type 'PostsComponent'

Tags: angular, mean

This is the error messenge:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/posts/posts.component.html:6:58 - error TS2339: Property 'addForm' does not exist on type 'PostsComponent'.
<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addForm(postForm)"> 

src/app/components/posts/posts.component.ts:7:16
templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
Error occurs in the template of component PostsComponent.
```

[image]

Remarkably, the error only occurs when i write the following line in the **posts.component.html** file:

```
<form #postForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addForm(postForm)">
```

This is what I have in **post/component.ts**:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css'],  
  providers: [PostService],
}) 
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

But I suppose the error is actually in **post.service.ts**, where the following line appears:

```
import { PostsComponent} from '../components/posts/posts.component'
```

In the introductory video I´m learning with (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccBtSAMFjto) at min 29:45 the line above appears written on line 4 **in an unexplained way**. Indeed, the last time that area of the screen is displayed is at min 24 and the line was absent.

When I write this line in my code it appears shaded as if it were missing a relationship, and the same doesn't happen in the video code. I guess this is related to my error as it has to do with "PostsComponent".

In min 17 of the video he has the same problem and seems to solve it by adding the following line in ** app.module.ts **:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

I find similar questions asked before, but can't figure out what the common cause is for discovering my mistake.

Comment: you have to define a method in order to use it, where is that `addForm` method defined? in Service?

Comment: In the video (min min 17:20) it seems to define it in app.module.ts
"import {FormsModule} from '@ angular / forms';" . I tried Edison's suggestion below and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creating  `addForm` Method in component fix your issue

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../../services/post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-posts',
  templateUrl: './posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./posts.component.css'],  
  providers: [PostService],
}) 
export class PostsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private postService: PostService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addForm(values){
  }

}
```

Comment: I added the "  addForm(){} " line and and the error stays the same.

Comment: please try changeing `addForm()` to `addForm(values)`,EG: i have updated my answer

Comment: Yes, it seems something has moved. But now I get the following error messenge: "src/app/components/posts/posts.component.html:8:87 - error TS2341: Property 'postService' is private and only accessible within class 'PostsComponent'."